# DynamoDB paginated data retrieval

Tags: node.js, go, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have the following columns and its purpose.

1. `id` -> stores the timestamp of modification
2. `authorName` -> saves the user name who have modified
3. `authorEmail` -> saves the user email who have modified
4. `version` -> value denoting the version number
5. `Data` -> a JSON object

Here, `version` can be considered as auto increment field which is incremented when modification happens.

The DynamoDB has partition key as id which is timestamp.

I want to create a GET API which orders all the records by version in descending order and applies a limit governed by pageSize constant.

Currently the architecture I thought of was by sending `LastEvaluatedKey` in response along with the data and next api call would pass this `LastEvaluatedKey` which will be my `ExclusiveStartKey` in the scan operation.

The issue as per my understanding is that the records cannot be ordered across multiple partitions.

Is there a way through which this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all items for a given `id` and sorted in desc order by `version` then you must use partition key: `id` and sort key: `version`

`SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id=123 LIMIT 5 DESC`

If you would like to maintain global order (order across all items) by version, then you will have to create a Global Secondary index and use a static partition key:

| gsipk | version | id | other |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 123 | data |
| 1 | 1 | 376 | data |
| 1 | 2 | 292 | data |
| 1 | 5 | 101 | data |
| 1 | 6 | 123 | data |
| 1 | 10 | 403 | data |
| 1 | 13 | 191 | data |
| 1 | 17 | 403 | data |

`SELECT * FROM myTable.myIndex WHERE gsipk=1 LIMIT 5 DESC`

Now that we use a static value for GSI partition key (`1`) I want to make you aware that this will limit your throughput to 1000 WCU per second, as that is the limit for a single partition. If you require more throughput than that, then you will have to make use of [GSI partition key sharding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html).